# Using different colors AND shapes in legend [Seaborn, Python]

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot, seaborn, legend-properties

I've read through [examples](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) on how to use different shapes and/or colors to separate data in a Seaborn plot. However, it seems that color and shapes are tied together, to show a separate variable.  For instance, in the following script (borrowed from the link above) it seems like you can *only* use green down arrows and grey up arrows:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", hue="time", palette=pal,
                  hue_order=["Dinner", "Lunch"],
                  hue_kws=dict(marker=["^", "v"]))
g = (g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", **kws).add_legend())
```

Is it possible to show, say, green up arrows *and* grey up arrows, *as well as* green down arrows and grey down arrows?

I've tried to define a dictionary for `col` in a similar fashion to what is being done for `hue`, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: You have two different levels of the hue variable but you are describing four glyphs. How does the mapping work?

Comment: The code snippet was taken from the example page linked above, not my current script. I was wondering if it could be expanded to include the 4 markers (grey/green up/down triangles)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you are taking advantage of some of the features of the `sns.FacetGrid` function. If you are just trying to make a simple scatter plot, then using `plt.scatter` directly is probably more straightforward.

Anyway, it seems possible to use whatever colors and symbols that you want in the FacetGrid example. I'm not a Seaborn pro, but here is one way to accomplish this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
kws = dict(s=50, linewidth=.5, edgecolor="w")
pal = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue',]
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", hue="size", palette=pal, hue_kws=dict(marker=["^", "^", "^", "v", "v", "v"]))
g = (g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", **kws).add_legend())

plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Dan, great answer -- exactly what I was looking for! Thank you -- if you happen to pass through Boulder again, crack open a cold one for me!

Comment: Happy to help an old friend :). I live in Boulder now! Just bought a house here. Let me know if you will be through - we have plenty of "cold ones" in stock.